# How trigger when DraggableScrollableSheet snaps to one of snapSizes values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `DraggableScrollableSheet` that are as follows:

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
            controller: _scrollController,
            expand: false,
            initialChildSize: 0.12,
            minChildSize: 0.12,
            maxChildSize: 0.99,
            snap: true,
            snapSizes: const [0.12, 0.6, 0.99],
            snapAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            builder: (ctx, sc) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: sc,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                     ....
                    ],
                  ),
              );
            },
          );
```

I want to refresh screen with `setState` when the sheet snaps to one of `[0.12, 0.6, 0.99]` values.

I tried to do this as following:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener((){
      setState(() { });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

In this case, the screen lags due to too many refreshes.

---

I tried to do this as following:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_sheetScrolls);
    super.initState();
  }

 void _sheetScrolls() {
    final double size = _scrollController.size.toPrecision(2);

    if ((size >= 0.1 && size <= 0.2) ||
        (size >= 0.5 && size <= 0.7) ||
        (size >= 0.9 && size <= 1))  {

       setState(() { });
    }

  }
```

In this case, sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it doesn't work.

What is the best way to implement this?